Limit of geometric series becoming logarithm?
Got this equation from WolframAlpha (Limit[Sum[4^(p/n)/n,{p,1,n}],n->∞]):
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{p=1}^n\frac{4^\frac{p}{n}}{n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{3*\sqrt[n]{4}}{(\sqrt[n]{4}-1)n}=\frac{3}{2\ln(2)}$$
Please explain the steps from the leftmost expression to the rightmost expression.
For context: I am looking for an alternative way to calculate change in function's value from one point to another (without using circular definite integral), and this came from Riemann sum of the function's derivative. Even though this is exactly the answer I need, I have no clue how n-th root turned into logarithm. 
I went through university Calculus course, which used Openstax textbooks. As I understand, these textbooks have only a handful of chapters on series, outlining basics. What books could be useful for learning more of Calculus?

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/973551

I suggest looking into real analysis, which is the next step.

If $n,p\in\Bbb N$, then\begin{align}\sum_{p=1}^n\frac{4^{p/n}}n&=\frac1n\sum_{p=1}^n\sqrt[n]4^p\\&=\frac1n\cdot\frac{\sqrt[n]4\left(\sqrt[n]4^n-1\right)}{\sqrt[n]4-1}\\&=\frac{3\sqrt[n]4}{n\left(\sqrt[n]4-1\right)},\end{align}and therefore$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{p=1}^n\frac{4^{p/n}}n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3\sqrt[n]4}{n\left(\sqrt[n]4-1\right)}=\frac3{\log4},$$since, for each $x>0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]x=1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\sqrt[n]x-1\right)=\log x$. More generally,$$x\in(0,\infty)\setminus\{1\}\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{p=1}^n\frac{x^{p/n}}n=\frac{x-1}{\log x}.$$

Where can I read more about the last bit? Both general case and my particular case don't seem intuitive at all. I found this post. To which topics does this formula connect?

I fail to see any connection between that post and my answer. Anyway, if you are not interested in it, please say so and I will delete it.
