# Limit Problem : Infinity Limit Problem

Tags: limits, indeterminate-forms

I can't find the way to solve this question and i always get 0/0.
The question is: $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty } x\left [ 2^{\frac{1}{x}}-1 \right ]$

From Mathematica, i get -infinity. But how can it done using manual method...? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting $x=\dfrac1h$

we have $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{2^h-1}h$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(e^{\ln 2})^h-1}h$$

$$=\ln2\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(e^{h\ln 2})-1}{h\ln2}=?$$

Comment: Oh... So we can set x become 1/h?

Comment: I think this also get infinity...

Comment: @user3658777, Do you know : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152605/proving-that-lim-limits-x-to-0-fracex-1x-1

Comment: it gets infinity, but from wolfram alpha and mathematica, it gets -infinity

Comment: @user3658777, It should be $\ln2\cdot1$