# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{e^x - 1 }{x} \right) $ without L'Hopital's rule

Tags: limits, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

I have to solve this limit:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \left( \dfrac{e^x - 1 }{x} \right) $$

I can easily do it by using hospital's rule, numerator becomes $e^0$ and denominator becomes $1$.

How should I solve that limit by using definition of $e$ as $e= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty } {\left( {1 + \frac 1n } \right)}^n$

Comment: Let n= 1/x.   Then "$x\to 0$" becomes "$n\to\infty$".

Comment: Can you use the series expansion of $e^{x}$?

Comment: You would use L'Hopital (involving computing the derivative of $\exp$ at $0$, and invoking a rather non-trivial theorem to conclude) to compute what is by definition the derivative of $\exp$ at $0$?

Comment: See [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152605/proving-that-lim-limits-x-to-0-fracex-1x-1?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan yes,I wanted to solve by using definition of x given in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1: Defintion of derivative**
Hint:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-e^0}{x-0}.$$

This is nothing but $\frac{d}{dx}e^x|_{x=0}$.

---

**Method 2:Taylor Series**

You could also plug in the definition of $e^x$ as a Taylor series and collect all higher order terms as $O(x^2)$:
$e^x=1+x+O(x^2)$.

---

**Method 3: Euler**

The last method was the method Euler used, which is not rigorous but still very nice.

Look at $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{a^x-1}{x}$$, Euler first showed convergence (not sure if he even cared about it :D) and then said that we want to choose $a$ such that the limit is $1$. So approximately
$$\frac{a^x-1}{x}\approx 1\implies a^x\approx 1+x \implies a \approx (1+x)^{1/x}.$$ 
Now, substitute $n=1/x$, hence $n\to \infty$ and we get
$$a\approx \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n=e$$

Answer (score 2):

You can see that:

$$\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\frac{e^x-e^0}{x-0}.$$

So since $x\mapsto e^x$ is differentiable,

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-e^0}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{d}{dx} (e^x)=\lim_{x\to 0}e^x=1.$$

Comment: This is basically a proof of l'Hospital rule. It does not answer OP's question...

Comment: Also, this is basically wrong. You are using continuity of the derivative of $\exp$, for *which* reason? (1) you do not need it, as this is the **definition** of $\exp'(0)$, (2) the same argument ought to work for functions whose derivative at $0$ exists, but who are not continuously differentiable.

Comment: No. This shows the limit it f'(x) while LH says that f/g has the same limit as f'/g'.

Comment: @martycohen Roberto's comment is wrong indeed, but so is the step which writes $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{d}{dx} e^x$ (it is only true here because $\exp$ is nice, but replacing $\exp$ by some $f$ differentiable at $0$ (and nowhere else) should still be OK in the OP's question). It should be $\frac{d}{dx} e^x \mid_{x=0}$, or even better $\exp'(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt
to use only integers.

To show
$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{e^x-1}{x}
= 0
$
using
$e
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac1{n}\right)^n
$.

From this,
$e^x
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac1{n}\right)^{nx}
$.

This is a double limit,
which is often problematical.

For general $x$,
this seems to require the
generalized binomial theorem.
To avoid this,
I will assume
$x = \frac1{m}$
as integer
$m \to \infty$,
and let
$n=km$
as integer $k \to \infty$.

Then
$e^{1/m}
= \lim_{k \to \infty} \left(1+\frac1{mk}\right)^{k}
$.
Now we can use the binomial theorem.

$\begin{array}\\
\left(1+\frac1{mk}\right)^{k}
&=\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}\frac1{(mk)^j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{\prod_{i=0}^{j-1}(k-i)}{j!}\frac1{(mk)^j}\\
\text{so}\\
f(m, k)
&=\dfrac{\left(1+\frac1{mk}\right)^{k}-1}{1/m}\\
&=m\sum_{j=1}^k \frac{\prod_{i=0}^{j-1}(k-i)}{j!}\frac1{(mk)^j}\\
&\le m\sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{j!}\frac1{m^j}\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{j!}\frac1{m^{j-1}}\\
&=1+ \sum_{j=2}^k \frac{1}{j!}\frac1{m^{j-1}}\\
&\le 1+ \frac1{m}\sum_{j=2}^k \frac{1}{j!}\frac1{m^{j-2}}\\
&= 1+ \frac1{m}\sum_{j=0}^{k-2} \frac{1}{(j+2)!}\frac1{m^j}\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$\sum_{j=0}^{k-2} \frac{1}{(j+2)!}\frac1{m^j}$
is easily shown 
to be bounded by
$1$
(actually,
by $\sum_{j=0}^{k-2} \frac{1}{(j+2)!} = e-2$),
$f(m, k)
\le 1+\frac1{m}$.

Since
$f(m, k)
\ge 1$
(from its first term),
$\lim_{m \to \infty} f(m, k)
= 1$.