# Proof of $f(x)=\sinh x \Rightarrow \frac{df}{dx}=\cosh x$ with definition of derivative.

Tags: limits, derivatives, hyperbolic-functions

I'm trying to prove that,

$$f(x)=\sinh x=\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2} \implies
\frac{df}{dx}=\cosh x=\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}$$

using the definition of derivative.

\begin{align}f(x)=\sinh x =\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}
&\frac{df}{dx}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{e^{x+h}-e^{-(x+h)}}{2}-\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}}{h} \\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{x+h}-e^{-x-h}-e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2h} \\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{x}e^{h}-e^{-x}e^{-h}-e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2h} \\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{x}(e^{h}-1)+e^{-x}(-e^{-h}+1)}{2h} \\
\end{align}

And I can't go anymore from here. How can I prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now use the fact that$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^h-1}h=1\text{ and }\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{-h}-1}h=-1,$$both of which follow from the fact that $\exp'(0)=1$.

Comment: Oh, I remember that $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{h}-1}{h}=1$ and $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{-h}-1}{h}=-1$. But I wonder how it is equal to $1$ or $-1$. Can you help me about it?

Comment: That is another question. I suggest that you post it as such.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It's an easy duplicate.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire [Sure.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176071/evaluating-lim-x-to-0-left-fracex-1-x-right-without-lhopital) I should have thought that.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you for your help. I'm happy with your answer :)